# $e^{xL}(x+x^3)<\frac{3\pi^2x}{L^2}$ for $x>0$ small enough and $L>0$ small enough

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, continuity

I'm trying to prove that $e^{xL}(x+x^3)<\frac{3\pi^2x}{L^2}$ for $x>0$ small enough and $L>0$ small enough and fixed, that is, there exists $\delta>0$ such that $e^{xL}(x+x^3)<\frac{3\pi^2x}{L^2}$ for $x \in (0,\delta)$.

However I'm stuck in this problem. I tried using continuity of functions but without success. So I plotted a graph to see if the result made sense and it seems that it does.

[image]that

Comment: As $L \to \infty$ RHS tends to $0$ so this  is false.

Comment: @geetha290krm Sorry, I forgot the hypothesis that L>0 is also small snough.

Answer (score 1):

It isn't true for every $L>0$ because

$$e^{xL}(x+x^3)=x+Lx^2+O(x^3)$$
as $x\to 0$.

Comment: What about $L>0$ small enough?

Comment: Yes, obviously for $L>0$ small enough it is true.

Comment: And how can we prove the affirmation in this case?